# Using react-native-snap-carousel how can i maintain scrubbing functionality without the carousel scrolling

Tags: react-native, carousel, victory-charts

I'm using a VictoryChart inside a carousel and i'm able to tap and hold (scrub) the data from the onActivated prop in VictoryVoronoiContainer but the carousel also scrolls with it. How can I get the carousel to not scroll when the user scrubs ?

There's a scrollEnabled prop I've been playing with that prevents the carousel from scrolling. However, if I do this, I'm not able to scrub the graph data. It will only read the data from the initial tap and ignores all the data that should be generated from dragging.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.